# Gwt doesn't run in IE and Chrome in local file system

Tags: gwt

Gwt application is client side only and it doesn't use any server
side functionality.Application will be run from user's local file system.
Builded application runs only in FireFox and doesn't work in IE and Chrome.
Can anyone says what is the reason?

Comment: what is the source of this statement? It works fine in Chrome with me.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where it stops? Does it enter onModuleLoad()? Have you tried running it in development mode?

Comment: I observed the same behaviour. Works in FF, but doesn't load in Chrome (under OS X).

Comment: If you're doing any AJAX requests at all (in this case not really to a "server", but to "client side" files), then probably you're experiencing [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787). That would at least explain it for Chrome. And maybe also for IE, if you have [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) installed.

Comment: I don't know if its enter onModileLoad. In development mode all works fine. I am using AJAX requests to load xml files for the application, maybe because of this I have these problems..

Answer (score 3):

GWT by default loads your compiled code in an iframe, and different files on the filesystem have different "origins", so the iframes cannot communicate with each others (they hit the Same Origin Policy).
This is a security measure.

You can use the `xs` or the new (2.1) `xsiframe` linkers instead, that load code through `<script>` tags. Just add this to your `gwt.xml`:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile the permutations for IS and Chrome?

GWT creates special JavaScript per Browser and language. Perhaps you only compiled for FF ?

Comment: I didn't define user.agent property in gwt.xml module. I complied the app for default browser, but I will try to compile it for specifed one.

Comment: It compiles for all browsers by default AFAIK.