# GWT Sample Project not working after compiling with no changes made

Tags: gwt, ant

I am following this tutorial for a Google Web Toolkit project: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted

Everything seems to work except at the very end when I call `ant build`.

```
C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp>ant build
Buildfile: C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\build.xml

libs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\lib

javac:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\build.xml:29: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\WEB-INF\classes

gwtc:
     [java] Compiling module com.impulse.mywebapp.MyWebApp
     [java]    Compiling 6 permutations
     [java]       Compiling permutation 0...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 1...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 2...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 3...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 4...
     [java]       Compiling permutation 5...
     [java]    Compile of permutations succeeded
     [java] Linking into C:\Users\Hebron\Dropbox\IP\gwt-2.5.1\MyWebApp\war\mywebapp
     [java]    Link succeeded
     [java]    Compilation succeeded -- 60.848s

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 5 seconds
```

It looks like the page built properly so when I go to open the MyWebApp.html file, it loads the static content without any issues. However, the textbox and submit button are both gone. When I ran `ant devmode` the textbox and button appeared and worked without any issues, so I'm just wondering why it doesn't work in 'production mode'.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gwt doesn't run in IE and Chrome in local file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357998/gwt-doesnt-run-in-ie-and-chrome-in-local-file-system) and [After compiling using GWT, only static elements shown in the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790532/after-compiling-using-gwt-only-static-elements-shown-in-the-page/15791087#15791087)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to serve your app from a web server.

Comment: I see, so when I was running it with `ant devmode` the application that was running acted as though it was my web server?

Comment: You were accessing through a `http://` URL yes. With the `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`, the code runs in Java through the plugin installed in your browser; without that part of the URL, and after compiling your app, you'd get the compiled app (useful if you don't have a web server at hand)